# Getting a list of a table's attributes that are sortable sorted by uniqueness

Tags: postgresql

I frequently use pg_dump to dump databases and compare them with diff.  To get rid of most "false positives", I'd like to patch pg_dump to sort the table so that its dumped order isn't changed more than necessary by insertions & Co.

So I'm looking for a query that will return a list of a table's attributes that are sortable (e. g. no XML fields) and sorted by "uniqueness", i. e. first attributes representing the primary key, then other unique keys, then the rest.

Before I dive into the depths of PostgreSQL's system catalogues, has anyone already solved this problem?

Comment: well... how big are those databases?

Comment: @SzymonGuz A typical dump of my private database is 400+ MByte.  Why does that matter?

Comment: presumably, because sorting each table will make the dump take a lot longer and consume more memory, which is why it doesn't do that currently.

Comment: @araqnid Well, the sorting should be negligible if it focuses on primary keys first, but if I'd care about the ressources, the database sorting should take a huge load off diff and the further analysis.

Answer (score 1):

You could write a bunch of queries like:

```
COPY (SELECT * FROM T ORDER BY ...) INTO t.csv
```

and write the result set of each table into a csv file. It will be written in the set ordering, so should be easily compared.

This is much easier than hacking pg_dump.

All the columns of a table you can get by using the standard INFORMATION_SCHEMA:

```
select * from information_schema.columns;
```

Comment: I know both, but hacking pg_dump isn't that hard, and I'm not interested in a list of all columns, but columns that are sortable sorted by uniqueness.

Comment: So write a proper query. I really don't get it why you want to solve not existing problems. On the other hand: you can always load both dumps into a database (400MB is a really small database) and compare that there using a bunch of simple queries.

Comment: Eh, the purpose of this question is to _find_ the proper query.  And when I (or git or rdiff-backup or ...) want to compare two dumps, loading them into a database is much more work (if even feasible) than tuning pg_dump.  Thanks anyway.